# How to extract Text in a React application to json react-intl translation files

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl, formatjs

So I'm trying to add languages support to a React application using react-intl.

The application has the Text in the JSX code.

Is there a tool that can scan the code and generate ids for each Text and replace the text with the generated id?? Or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Scan the code.?

Comment: Yes, reads the code, figure out the text, copy them in file, assign an id, replace the text with an id.

Answer (score 0):

Probably https://formatjs.io/docs/tooling/babel-plugin is what you need but I'm not sure. It's a babel plugin which can remove translation messages and generate message ids.

**Edit**: **Wrong answer.** In project there is no FormattedMessage components but only pure texts.

Comment: That's for if you already have the plain text as FomattedText with an assigned id. it just extract them in file for you.

Comment: You have custom Text component with text which you need to convert to FormattedText?

Comment: for example <Button icon="pi pi-minus" onClick={collapseAll} >Collapse All</Button> should became <Button icon="pi pi-minus" onClick={collapseAll} ><FomattedText id="generated.id"/></Button>

Comment: Then you can regex replace in project with your editor but id you will have to write manually. Or you can write a script that will replace and generate ids in each file.